# getting unauthorized error trying to listen to Azure Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

i have a simple EventHub listener sample code trying to listen to event hub

```
public class Program
{



    private const string EventHubConnectionString = "Endpoint=sb://fake.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=SendETB;SharedAccessKey=JcvVeX5KsGHfJkPNmdns5jvNYVpB9Wc05jDuMaV3NW8=";
    private const string EventHubName = "myhub";
    private const string StorageContainerName = "my-own-container";
    private const string StorageAccountName = "mystorage";
    private const string StorageAccountKey = "fakeZn8WUV1mcsh0MVbmea/ypxDs+No2tzrhr0kUmjxvA0a0jUxfZ29hHoY/yopVvGLEn/stEQbBEAyjYMX9g==";



    private static readonly string StorageConnectionString = string.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1}", StorageAccountName, StorageAccountKey);

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    private static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Registering EventProcessor...");

        var eventProcessorHost = new EventProcessorHost(
            EventHubName,
            PartitionReceiver.DefaultConsumerGroupName,
            EventHubConnectionString,
            StorageConnectionString,
            StorageContainerName);

        // Registers the Event Processor Host and starts receiving messages
        await eventProcessorHost.RegisterEventProcessorAsync<SimpleEventProcessor>();

        Console.WriteLine("Receiving. Press enter key to stop worker.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        // Disposes of the Event Processor Host
        await eventProcessorHost.UnregisterEventProcessorAsync();
    }
}
```

}

with the above mentioned code i get an error.

> Error on Partition: 0, Error: Unauthorized access. 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://fake.servicebus.windows.net/etbhub/consumergroups/$default/partitions/0'. TrackingId:fakef417d94238ba36d41d32b83341_G9, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2020-01-27T22:06:49

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error message is pretty self-descriptive. Make sure SharedAccessKeyName SendETB allows 'Listen' permission. You can check it on the portal like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added a Shared Access Policy for **Listen** for your **Event Hub Namespace**.

For Event Hub it should be Send

For Event Hub Namespace it should have all three Manage, Sen, Listen as per the need.